# Ganymed SSH - Changing user

Tags: java, shell, ssh

I'd like to automate a few tasks I am doing on multiple machines. I would like to use Ganymed's SSH2 library for this task. I am already capable of running multiple commands, getting the response from the server as well as a few other small things. The thing is that you can only execute one command per session which is why my execute method looks like the following in order to allow me to use one method for multiple commands:

```
    public String execCmd(String cmd) throws IOException {
    sess = conn.openSession();
    sess.execCommand(cmd);
    InputStream stdout = new StreamGobbler(sess.getStdout());
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stdout));
    String result = br.readLine();
    br.close();
    sess.close();
    return (result);
}
```

The thing is that I seem unable to change my user using "su"+username. I read that the "su" command opens a new shell resulting in this issue.

Now - what would be the cleanest method to resolve this? I read about the possibility of opening a shell using this library but I fail to write to it and I seem unable to locate any examples for it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to execute multiple commands. You have to request a pseudo terminal and start a shell. The commands are Session.requestPTY() and Session.startShell().

Comment: @Mr.Stef and how am I going to write to this shell? Using sessions I had the option to execute commands, this isn't the case for the shell I think

Comment: You have to get the outstream. outstream = this.session.getStdin() and then you can use Writer. final BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(this.outputStream));

Comment: Can one of you move the answer from the comments into an actual answer please. I would do it but I don't deserve the reputation for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to execute multiple commands. You have to request a pseudo terminal and start a shell afterwards. From the session object get the outstream to execute the commands.

```
 ...
    sess.requrequestPTY();
    sess.startShell();
    Outstream outstream = sess.getStdin();
    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outstream));
    final String cmd = new String(command);
    bufferedWriter.write(cmd); 
    bufferedWriter.flush();
    ...
```

Comment: Ok, I thoght I am getting it but I am not. How do I write to it? Using bufferedWriter.write("sudo reboot"); results in nothing. This issue is confusing me more than I thought

Comment: Do you flush the writer? I will add the full code to the answer.

Comment: Hi, thanks for you reply. I figured out how to send commands using the shell:         sess.requestPTY("bash");
        sess.startShell();

        BufferedWriter wr = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(sess.getStdin(), "utf-8"));
        wr.write("echo test\n");
        but I seem unable to get the output from the server, any advice? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I used an BufferedReader together with channel conditions. Take a look at sess.waitForCondition(). What I can reccoment is putting the reading into an observer pattern.This worked well for me.

Comment: Not sure why this got down rated?